# Can you create a png image file with AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, pdf, png, dpi

I am using `AVFoundation` and capturing the still image output and creating a jpeg image file.  This is working great.  All the documentation and sample code I have been able to come across has always created a jpeg file, but I would like to create a png file to preserve the pixel value so I can create a higher quality (at least 300 dpi) PDF from the image.  I need a higher quality PDF for OCR Recognition purposes.

I have the `AVCaptureSession` set as:  `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`, and the image I see on my screen is high quality, but the PDF that I create from the jpeg file is below 300 dpi.

Does anybody have any pointers for me for either creating a png file, or how to beef up the dpi on a PDF generated from a jpeg?